# Why does my if statement work with an else if, but not an OR operator

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operator-keyword, or-operator

I wrote a small piece of JS in the console, to loop through recommended connections on LinkedIn and if the text contains a certain word, ignore that card, otherwise click the 'X' close button.

Initially I wrote it like this:

```
const list = document.querySelector('.mn-pymk-list__cards');
const cards = list.querySelectorAll('.mn-pymk-list__card');

cards.forEach( (card, i) => {

  setTimeout( ()=>{
    let text = card.querySelector('.member-insights__count');

    if( !text.textContent.includes('Sharon') || text === null ) {
        card.querySelector('.pymk-card__close-btn').click();
       } else {
        card.style.background = 'green';
       }
  }, i * 1000 )

});
```

However, when it ran, it would sometimes error (whilst continuing to iterate) with 'Could not read textContent of null'.

However, when I wrote the code like this:

```
const list = document.querySelector('.mn-pymk-list__cards');
const cards = list.querySelectorAll('.mn-pymk-list__card');

cards.forEach( (card, i) => {

  setTimeout( ()=>{
    let text = card.querySelector('.member-insights__count');

    if( text === null ) {
        card.querySelector('.pymk-card__close-btn').click();
    } else if (!text.textContent.includes('Sharon')) {
        card.querySelector('.pymk-card__close-btn').click();
    } else {
        card.style.background = 'green';
    }
  }, i * 1000 )

});
```

It runs absolutely fine and does what I want it to.

QUESTION: I can't understand why the first option doesn't work, as it seems more concise and theoretically should do the same thing?

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that on LinkedIn, some of the suggested contacts don't have a class of '.member-insights__count' and instead have '.member-insights__info'.

But, that should still make text resolve to null, right?

Any insight would be great!

Comment: Your error suggests that the element you're trying to grab with `let text = card.querySelector('.member-insights__count');` isn't grabbed and thus `textContent` can't be read on the element stored in `text` because there is nothing stored in `text`

Comment: "I suspect it has something to do with the fact that on LinkedIn, some of the suggested contacts don't have a class of '.member-insights__count' and instead have '.member-insights__info'." it sounds like you already solved your question. If no matches are found with querySelector, it will return `null`. OH i see yes you need to swap your || conditions, `text == null` will short circuit the or statement and not try to evaluate the second part.

Comment: Simply because if `text` is null it won't be able to access `textContent`. If you switch the order of the operands of the `||` you could achieve the same effect as with the `else if` statement (it won't evaluate the rhs if the lhs is truthy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if( !text.textContent.includes('Sharon') || text === null ) {
```

What would you expect this code to do when `text` is null? It will crash because you can't access properties or methods of null.

You need to check for null first.

```
if( text === null || !text.textContent.includes('Sharon') ) {
```

Comment: So in IF statements using OR operators, you can't simply put to things that are evaluated at the same time? I was assuming you see that `text` would simply equal `null` and therefore whilst the left hand side of the IF does nothing (or errors) the right hand side would sort it out... I didn't know an IF could crash so to speak :) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @WillOSW: They don't get evaluated at the same time, no. They get evaluated in the order they appear. And in the case of JavaScript, once the overall condition is true, then no more conditions are tested. By switching them around, as I have it, the `textContent` property is never evaluated when `text` is null. And so you don't get the error.

Comment: "They get evaluated in the order they appear" Worth mentioning [Javascript's operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

If textContent is null (e.g. as you said, the  contact has '.member-insights__info' instead), `!text.textContent.includes('Sharon')` will cause the error message.

In the second version, that line can only be reached if the text isn't null.

Comment: Right ok, but if that part of the IF statement causes an error, won't it still run because the other side of the `or` will be equal to null  `text === null`  ?

Comment: It doesn't check them at the same time, it does one after the other. So first it will check `!text.textContent.includes('Sharon')`, THEN `text === null`. so it hits the first part and fails. As others have said, if you check for null first, it will only check  `!text.textContent.includes('Sharon')` if the text is not null.

Answer (score 1):

The `||` operator will only evaluate the 2nd argument if the first argument is false.

In your case the only difference between the first and second code snippets is the order in which you check if the value is null

What you need to do is check for null first like this:

```
if( text === null ||  !text.textContent.includes('Sharon')) {
```

This way it will only check if `text` includes specific text once it's determined that `text` is not null